# FallbackResource responds with 500 error when request is anything but a file in the directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file  in my document root I am using the FallbackResource Directive to handle most of my URLs.  It works when the urls are requesting files within the document root, but when they request a subdirectory or something in a subdirectory, it responds with a 500 error.  Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^(Contact-Us|Driving-Directions|About-Us|Services|Sitemap)(?:\.html|\.php)?$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^vCards/([A-Z]+)\.vcf$ vCard?n=$1 [L,NC]


FallbackResource index.php
```

When ever I remove the FallbackResource directive, it returns a 404 instead.

The server logs contain the following errors:

```
[Fri Jan 09 16:42:20 2015] [error] [client 108.48.69.131] Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable confguration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Fri Jan 09 16:42:20 2015] [error] [client 108.48.69.131] No user or group set - set suPHP_UserGroup 
[Fri Jan 09 16:42:20 2015] [error] [client 108.48.69.131] unable to include "500.php" in parsed file /usr/local/apache/htdocs/500.shtml
```

I do not have permission to set the LogLevel

Example:

1. [HOST-HERE]/fakePage (Handled Correctly)
2. [HOST-HERE]/fakePage/ (500 Error)
3. [HOST-HERE]/fake/reallyFake (500 Error)
4. [HOST-HERE]/fake/reallytotalfake/ (500 Error)

Comment: Did you try using a / before index.php? Did you try to use the absolute path (e.g. /var/www/clients/a001/web/index.php)?

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski To answer your first question, that was the first thing I tried, which gave me 404 errors no matter what.  I have not tried your second proposal.  Is that known to work?

Comment: It could.. Depending on other bits and bytes.

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski The absolute path did the same thing as the leading slash—404s no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that with `FallbackResource`.

But you can with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I think you can as noted in the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) "Use this to set a handler for any URL that doesn't map to anything in your filesystem, and would otherwise return HTTP 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Yes, but for all directories the same file or that file in the directory ?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain your question differently?  I don't quite understand your wording.

Comment: Just try with my answer... because I know that work for all the site. I don't know for FallbackResource. (if FallbackResource try to find this file in each directories or not)

Comment: Would I put it exactly where the FallbackResource Directive is now?

Comment: Yes, after the last RewriteRule.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions—could you explain how the single carrot symbol means any request?

Comment: First I test with `-d` (for directory) and `-f` (file) if they exists or not. And after that I can redirect if it's not the case (`!` is for not). And `^` is a short for all cases. (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Oh, I never knew that you could use ^ to mean all cases.  I will try it now.

Comment: I am going to give this a up vote and mark it as answered, but I still would like to know why it does not work.

Comment: Thanks. For me, it's because FallbackResource look for this resource in this directory, not in the all domain... just my idea